# What version of [insert npm module here] do I have?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm picking up a project I had in Node.js. It worked fine but it didn't go to production because lacking time.

I updated node, express and socket io with

```
npm update [package name] -g
```

I know that `-g` states for global but I'm not sure if I installed in this way on the server so, my questions are:

How do I know which version my app has?

If I need to update just for that app, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[npm ls](http://npmjs.org/doc/list.html) - list installed packages

Comment: to add to this: `npm ls -g` will list the globally installed packages, `npm ls` from within your app's directory will show you what your app currently uses.